# How to set the interval of ticks on the X-Axis using dimple.js

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I am using the following code to plot some data related to the passengers of the titanic by age using dimple.js:

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var ageAxis = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Age"); 
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Survived");
myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
ageAxis.addOrderRule('Age',false);
ageAxis.ticks=5; // this doesn't seem to work unfortunately
myChart.draw();
```

I get the following chart:

[image]

I want to define an interval for the ticks in the x axis to only display some of them

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `ageAxis.timeInterval = 5;`

Comment: @MahmutKilic I tried but it didn't work, I think this works only for Time Axis and it does't work for me since I am using a Category Axis. thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the excess labels after drawing as explained in the answer here:

[cleaning axis in dynamic charts in dimple.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312940/cleaning-axis-in-dynamic-charts-in-dimple-js/25313793#25313793)